# Object created in js.erb file not available to .js file on page load, but is with dev tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I create an array in a filename.js.erb file. I then try to iterate through that array in a difFile.js file, but I get an error that the array is not defined. However, when I open up devtools I have full access to the array.

I've precompiled my assets (and clobbered them first just to be sure). I'm guessing this has something to do with the manner/order Rails precompiles the assets but I can't find the answer in the docs.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once the `filename.js.erb` file has been delivered to the client (as a normal js file, of course), how does the `difFile.js` know to do something? Do you call a function in the `difFile.js` file? If you store the array in a namespace, that might work (something like `arraySpace.array = [1,2]`). Of course, `arraySpace` has to be defined beforehand (`arraySpace = {}`) in the `difFile.js`

Comment: @RyanK Thanks for the suggestions. I tried namespacing and still got the same error. Yes, I am calling a function in my difFile.js, and would receive an error that the variable in filename.js.erb was not defined, yet when I opened up devtools and either called the variable directly or the function it worked fine. Some sort of load-order issue that I still don't fully understand. If you know a better way to do this than the answer I provided below I'm happy to change the answer to one that you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I ended up doing was copying the code from my difFile.js to the filename.js.erb file. Not so good with the separation of concerns, but it's working.